# Froala Editor not referencing jQuery

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, froala

I'm trying to use Froala editor in my Angular4 App. This is an .NET Core project using Javascript Services and Angular2SpaTemplate.

Here is my configuration:

```
// [ webpack.config.vendor.js ]
...
module.exports = (env) => {
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            ...
            'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
            'froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.css',
            'froala-editor/css/froala_style.css',
            'jquery'
            ...
        ]
    },
    plugins: {
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}

// [ Layout.module.ts ]
// I created a LayoutModule, to group all layout stuff

// Import the Froala Editor plugin.
import "froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js";

// Import Angular plugin.
import { FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule } from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        // Froala
        FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(),
        FroalaViewModule.forRoot()
    ],
    exports: [
        ...
        FroalaEditorModule,
        FroalaViewModule,
    ]
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

Then I import the Layout module in any other module where its components will be used, Thus I have a module with a component which I want to use froala,

```
// [ mycomponent.html ]
<textarea [froalaEditor] class="form-control" name="summary" id="summary" formControlName="summary"></textarea>
```

Everything compiles fine, I can run from the command line the following commands with no issues.

```
webpack 
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

At runtime, the component throws this exception.

```
ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at new FroalaEditorDirective (editor.directive.js:29)
at createClass (vendor.js?v=p9mu7NwAjYIo1I3QMys0zFQ6NBHDtn3nUqAYWCqMzNw:15748)
at createDirectiveInstance (vendor.js?v=p9mu7NwAjYIo1I3QMys0zFQ6NBHDtn3nUqAYWCqMzNw:15579)
at createViewNodes (vendor.js?v=p9mu7NwAjYIo1I3QMys0zFQ6NBHDtn3nUqAYWCqMzNw:17007)
at callViewAction (vendor.js?v=p9mu7NwAjYIo1I3QMys0zFQ6NBHDtn3nUqAYWCqMzNw:17451)
at execComponentViewsAction (vendor.js?v=p9mu7NwAjYIo1I3QMys0zFQ6NBHDtn3nUqAYWCqMzNw:17360)
at createViewNodes (vendor.js?v=p9mu7NwAjYIo1I3QMys0zFQ6NBHDtn3nUqAYWCqMzNw:17034)
at createRootView (vendor.js?v=p9mu7NwAjYIo1I3QMys0zFQ6NBHDtn3nUqAYWCqMzNw:16902)
at callWithDebugContext (vendor.js?v=p9mu7NwAjYIo1I3QMys0zFQ6NBHDtn3nUqAYWCqMzNw:18283)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (vendor.js?v=p9mu7NwAjYIo1I3QMys0zFQ6NBHDtn3nUqAYWCqMzNw:17600)
```

I don't know where the problem is, apparently $ (jQuery) is not being imported as expected.

Any point to the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because jQuery is not visible globally. Maybe it would work if you add the following in your `main.ts`:

```js
import * as $ from 'jquery';
window["$"] = $;
window["jQuery"] = $;
```

Comment: I'd like to know what's the **new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            ...
        }** for. I thought that imports jquery. Anyway, adding those lines worked.

Comment: It makes jQuery available globally.

Comment: Wow it worked, but my prob is now editor is coming but without css. I have included css in my .angular_cli.json file.